# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $K = \{x \in G: xax^{-1} \in H \iff a \in H\}$. Prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Closure under multiplication:

$\to$

Let $a, x, y \in H.$  Since $H$ is closed under inverses and multiplication, $xax^{-1} \in H$ and $yay^{-1} \in H.$ Since $H$ is closed under multiplication, $xyax^{-1}y^{-1} \in H.$

$\leftarrow$

Suppose $xyax^{-1}y^{-1} \in H$, then $a \in H$ since $H$ is closed under multiplication. So, $xy \in K.$

Closure under inverses:

Since $H$ is closed under multiplication and inverses, if $a \in H,$ then $x^{-1}ax \in H.$ If $x^{-1}ax \in H,$ then $a \in H$ because $H$ is a group. So, $x^{-1} \in K.$

Identity:

Suppose $a \in H.$ Then $a = eae^{-1} \in H.$ So, $e \in H.$

I'd like to see how I can fix/improve this proof.

Comment: Could you write all assumptions in the question instead of splitting things between title and question? I'm not sure I read either the question of the premises (or both) correctly

Comment: @ Alex H., I am not sure what you're asking, but I edited my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly fine. There is a bit of an issue with your proof that $K$ is closed under multiplication.  Let $x,y\in K$ and $a\in H$.

$$\begin{align}
a\in H & \implies yay^{-1}\in H\\
& \implies xyay^{-1}x^{-1}\\
& \implies xy\in K.
\end{align}$$

Comment: @ Tim Raczkowski, you got the second implication because $H$ is closed under multiplication/inverses, right? How did you get the third one($xy \in K$)?

Comment: I applied conjugation by $x$ to the previous line.

Comment: Like so: $xyay^{-1}x^{-1} \cdot x = xy$? Is it possible because of the closure under multiplication?

Comment: Since $(xy)a(xy)^{-1}\in H$, $xy$ satisfies the condition required for it to be in $K$.

Comment: Oh I see what you did: $xyay^{-1}x^{-1} = xya(xy)^{-1}.$ Cool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show just two things: $e \in K$ and $x \in K \implies x^{-1} \in K$.

Comment: I think you also need to show if $a \in K$ and $b \in K$, then $ab \in K.$

Comment: The OP has already shown closure so I did not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subgroup criterion. Obviously $e \in K$ so $K \neq \emptyset$.

Let $x, y \in K$, then $xax^{-1} \in H$ and $y^{-1}ay \in H$ for all $a \in H$, but then $$xy^{-1}a(xy^{-1})^{-1} = xy^{-1}ayx^{-1} = x(y^{-1}ay)x^{-1} \in A$$ and you're done.

Answer (score -1):

Since $H$ is a group, the identity element $e$ is in $H$. Also, for any $x$ in $G$, $xex^{-1}=e\in H$ so for any $x\in G, x\in K$. In other words $G\subseteq K$, but also by definition, $K\subseteq G$. So $K=G$.