# Show a group to be a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $K = \{x \in G: xax^{-1} \text { iff } a \in H\}.$ Prove $H$ is a subgroup of $K$.

Suppose $a \in H.$ Then $aaa^{-1} = a \in H.$ So, $a \in K.$ Thus, $H \subseteq K.$ Since $H$ is a group, $H$ s a subgroup of $K$. Would that work?

Comment: Should that say $xax^{-1}\in H$?

Comment: I suspect you are also supposed to show $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @ AMPerrine, $xax^{-1} \in H,$ but $aaa^{-1} =a$, and $a \in H.$

Comment: @ David Wheeler, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168396/let-h-be-a-subgroup-of-g-let-k-x-in-g-xax-1-in-h-iff-a-in-h/1168410#1168410.

Comment: @Max, I know how to answer that question, I'm pointing out to the OP that just showing $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ contained in a subset of $G$ isn't enough....

Comment: Why do you ask the same question two times? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168396/let-h-be-a-subgroup-of-g-let-k-x-in-g-xax-1-in-h-iff-a-in-h

Comment: @ Winther, $K$ is defined exactly the same both times, but the questions are different.

Comment: @ David Wheeler, do you think subgroup test need to be applied here?

Answer (score 0):

No.

To show that a set is a subgroup of a group, it doesn't suffice to show that it contains another subgroup.

For instance consider the quaternion group: $$Q_8 = \{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$$ and the subset $\{\pm1, \pm i, \pm j\}$. This contains the subgroup $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$ but is not a subgroup itself.

The question you linked to in the comments has a few good answers on how to show it is a subgroup.